# How to get PreConditions working from Java applied changelogs?

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to use PreConditions to skip CreateTable changesets and MARK_RAN if the table exists.  The PreConditions seem to be ignored as Liquibase logs a table exists error as it tries to create an existing table in MYSQL (in AWS Aurora).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.10.xsd">

    <changeSet author="xxx" id="1231">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <not>
                <tableExists tableName="tenant"/>
            </not>
        </preConditions>
        <createTable tableName="tenant">
            <column autoIncrement="true" name="tenantId" type="int(11)">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"
                    unique="false" />
            </column>
         ...
```

The changelogs are being applied using the following Java code:

```
            final Database dataBase = DatabaseFactory.getInstance()
                    .findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
            final Liquibase liquiBase = new liquibase.Liquibase(CHANGE_LOG_FILE, RESOURCE_ACCESSOR, dataBase);
            liquiBase.update(CONTEXTS, LABEL_EXPRESSION);
```

The error:

```
Response: {"errorMessage":"Failed to connect to Liquibase due to Migration failed for change set db.changelog-1.1.xml::1231::xxx:\n     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'tenant' already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE xxx_global.tenant (tenantId INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, region VARCHAR(255) NULL, tenantName VARCHAR(255) NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_TENANT PRIMARY KEY (tenantId))]"}
```

My only other thought would be to try to use a custom context on the CreateTable changesets for clean installations

Comment: specifying a context is not working either

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and it was not a Liquibase issue.  The AWS stack containing the Lambda code to call Liquibase was not updating.  I deleted and recreated the stack and it started working.